# Grant custom permissions to user in mysql

Tags: mysql, privileges

How could I create a user with specific user permissions, for example, I have a database called `mydb`, and it has these tables: `users, contacts, messages`, and I want to create a user called `app_admin` with the following permissions:

- Create, Update & Drop tables
- Insert, Update, Select & Delete data from tables

In order to do that what do I have to do?, Is it possible to do it in one line?

I know how to grant most of the privileges and create user in one line (thanks to Richard St-Cyr):

```
GRANT ALTER, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON db.* TO 'app_admin'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '_my_securePass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

But what I don't want the user to be able to Drop the database.

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, also try this example

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON mydb.* TO 'app_admin'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this can be done in 1 line by specifying the list of privileges instead of ALL. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html for the list of privileges.

```
GRANT ALTER, CREATE, DELETE, DROP, INSERT, SELECT, UPDATE ON db.* TO 'app_admin'@localhost IDENTIFIED BY '_my_securePass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Would you like to make an example with the permissions I listed?

Comment: Won't `DROP` let the user drop the database?

Comment: That's correct. The user can `DROP` the database  or any object in the database. `DROP` is used for both the database and the object in it.

Comment: But I don't want the user to be able to drop the database, just tables... How could I do that?

Comment: I don't know how you could achieve this, except by granting permissions on specific tables. Maybe someone else will give you and answer.